Why was my question about sexual orientation reduction got automatically deleted by "community" if it wasn't closed?
I have no idea why this question, which wasn't closed and had only one down vote, was deleted.

What is the main component of sexual orientation?
From vast reading on the formation of sexual orientation I understand
  that all researchers, from all "political camps" accept that sexual
  orientation can have at least one of these expressions:

Visual 
Odiological
Tacital (body touch)
Pheromonal (body odor)
Lingual (body taste)

I can testify that as a person romato-erotically attracted to women,
  if I see Muslim girls covered in Hijab (let alone niqab), I usually
  feel no "sexual arousal" but if I see girls with very long straight
  black hair , I usually do feel somewhat "sexual arousal";
That brought me to assume that any of the five components of sexual
  orientation might have sub components and that, humbly, if to be
  somewhat technical, in regards to the visual component applicable to
  non blind people, face and hair are the most romanto-erotically
  arousing body organ, by sexual orientation.
What is the main component of sexual orientation (by what research
  tell us)?

Why was my question about sexual orientation reduction got automatically deleted by "community" if it wasn't closed?

Downvoted questions (more specifically, questions with a negative net voting score) that remain unanswered for a period of time are auto-deleted by the bot.
Quite a few of your questions have not been well received by the community. Have you taken the tour and did you visit the help-center, notably the page on which questions to avoid?   

I suggest you to delete the comment-question in your answer-including-post; you shouldn't have a problem to delete it as you have deleted an entire correspondence in the comments of that post.

I am now emailing the community managers about this mismanagement-according-to-my-opinion.

Feel free to email SE corp. Disrespectful discourse is indeed deleted as it goes against the 'be kind' convention here on SE. As said, I am just trying to help. Therefore, I see no reason at all editing my answer. Cheers.

Humbly I already felt free because I had not reason to feel not to (again a redundant saying ATMO); I found all of your comments at least partly disrespectful and certainly not trying to help and I say this with 7 years experience in the community. Cheers.

@JohnDoea - my responses weren't meant that way. The comments are hidden in the background (not deleted, just not visible) so SE corp can easily review them if they want to. I don't have anything to hide, I just don't wish to have offensive material on our site. Anyway, this is not leading anywhere, so perhaps it is best that SE corp intervenes at this point. Thanks for reaching out to them.

I don't believe that also. I think you should have notify me (at least from web accessibility standpoint) that the comments weren't deleted but were only hidden; your comments were to me at least partially offensive; it might lead to make you a better moderator by commenting comments only at the comment section (a gold principle of mine) and by notifying comments are going to be hidden.
